# What is col[:2] and col[4:] doing when iterating through column headers in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to pandas.  For a DataFrame with Olympic results, the question was to change the column names through iterating the column headers and then use rename to rename the column names.  In the given answer, I don't understand what col[:2] is doing, and in the rename parameters, what is col[4:] doing?  Can you please help me understand what the code is doing? Thanks. (Sorry I'm not allowed to embed pictures so the dataframes before and after are in the links.)
[dataframe_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhfl6.png)
[dataframe_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkcpZ.png)

The given code is:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Gold' + 
    col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:2]=='02':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Silver' + 
    col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:2]=='03':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze' + 
    col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:1]=='№':
    df.rename(columns={col:'#' + 
    col[1:]}, inplace=True)
```

df.head()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dataframe before the change, the column headers have a specific structure. Each header will begin with `01` for Gold, `02` for Silver and `03` for Bronze. After the first two characters, it might have other identifying information. But as I can see from the earlier dataframe, the identifying information is separated from the first two letters by a `newline` character and a `!` character (example: `01\n!.123`, `03\n!.456`). The aim of the code is to replace the first two digits by their respective medal types without changing the following information.

`col[:2]` indexes all letters before position `2`, that is, the first two letters and replaces them with the appropriate medal type. We do not want the remaining information to change, but we also want to discard the intervening `newline` and the `!` characters. So we just take everything from the fourth position in the original name which already skips over the first two (already replaced) and the intervening characters that we do not want, and add this to the medal names we just created. `col[4:]` does precisely that.

I have assumed certain things about the names of the original dataframe. Please let me know if any of those assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much Satwik! Sorry, one more question, isn't the column header a string? So we can use this format col[:2] to slice the string? Thanks!

Comment: @pkhiev Yes, Strings can be indexed in a way similar to lists. It cannot however be changed when indexing it. For example, for a list `l` you can do `l[:2] = ['x', 'y']` but for a string that will not be allowed. See immutable and mutable objects in python for more detail.